# AWS mediastore java sdk 2 - enable public access

Tags: aws-mediastore

I want to enable public access to objects in my mediastore container, something like in s3
...
s3Client.createBucket(CreateBucketRequest
.builder()
.bucket(bucketName).acl(BucketCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ).acl(BucketCannedACL.PUBLIC_READ_WRITE)
...

Answer (score 0):

To enable public access, you need to add a stanza to the Container Policy. The additional stanza will resemble this example below. Modify it using your AWS account number, region, and container name in the Resource ARN.

```
{
      "Sid": "PublicReadOverHttps",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "mediastore:GetObject",
        "mediastore:DescribeObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:mediastore:myregion:9999999999:container/MyContainer/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```